# How to load and render data: URL in browser using Codeception?

Tags: codeception

I need to load `data:text/html, <html><body><img src=https://example.com/image.jpg></body></html>` in Omnibox using Codeception, to render such web page in browser.

`$I->amOnURL` will fail because of `Wrong URL passes, host and scheme not set`

`$I->ExecuteJS` will fail because it is [forbidden](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/blink-dev/GbVcuwg_QjM/GsIAQlemBQAJ) to use data: links by JS

Does anyone have any idea how it can be achieved ?

Comment: haven't you got a proper URL to open your page with?

Comment: Nope. Otherwise I would use amOnURL or amOnPage